# Reporting Services & MDX Queries with parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, mdx

I have an MDX query that works with fin years (ie 1213, 1314, 1415) which is returned by a parameter @FYear.

Is it possible to alter the parameter to the previous finyear?

So if the user selected fin year 1314 the value would be 1213.

In access I could used somthing like this:

```
IIf(Len(Left(@FYear,2)-1)>1,Left(@FYear,2)-1,Format((Left(@FYear,2)-1),"00")) & IIf(Len(Right(@FYear,2)-1)>1,Right(@FYear,2)-1,Format((Right(@FYear,2)-1),"00"))
```

but it does not seem to work in here. The error I get is "Query (16, 16) Operator or expression '&' is not supported in this context."

I have tried to concatenate the 2 IIfs with +""+ and &""& but no luck.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you could share the MDX query which uses this..Also, where and how is this parameter getting consumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a reporting application like `SSRS` to consume this parameter. If `@FYear` returns numeric values of the likes of 1213, 1314 etc from the font end, you would have to first fashion it up a bit to look like a hierarchy member. Something like this..

```
"Calendar.FinYear.&[" + @FYear + "]"//----->It would now look like Calendar.FinYear.&[1314]
```

Now, if you are to use this parameter in the MDX query, you HAVE to convert this into a set. This is a string right now. So you want to use the `StrToSet` function.

```
StrToSet("Calendar.FinYear.&[" + @FYear + "]")
```

Finally, you said you want to actually get to the previous financial year.

In the MDX hierarchy tree, the members are staceked up one after other like so - 
    1011 
    1112 
    1213 
    1314 
    1415 and so on..

There are multiple ways to reach the member "1213" from the member "1314". One of the easiest would be using the `PrevMember` function.

Finally, your parameter would look like -

```
StrToSet("Calendar.FinYear.&[" + @FYear + "].PrevMember")
```

But, all said and done, if you still insist on reaching the prev member in the way you described above, then two minor adjustments.

Firstly, use the `+` operator to concatenate and secondly, cast the left and right bits to string(Might work without this as well, but just to be on the safer side)

```
CStr(IIf(
    Len(Left(@FYear,2)-1)>1, 
    Left(@FYear,2)-1,
    Format((Left(@FYear,2)-1),"00"))) 
+

CStr(IIf(
    Len(Right(@FYear,2)-1)>1,
    Right(@FYear,2)-1,
    Format((Right(@FYear,2)-1),"00")))
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** 
For debugging -

Try having just

```
StrToSet("[Discharge Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[1314].PrevMember")
```

If this works, then there is no issue with the `MDX`. You should probably check the parameter in `SSRS`. It is **not** returning `1314` I feel. Could be a format issue as well.

Comment: Thanks Sourav_Agasti, When I try {[Discharge Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[1314].PrevMember} it works but when I try {StrToSet("[Discharge Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[" + @FYear + "].PrevMember")} the fields are blank no error message.

Comment: Is the parameter returning you "1314"?

Comment: Sorry, {[Discharge Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[1314].PrevMember} will return 1213 data, but then I try  {StrToSet("[Discharge Date].[Fiscal Date].[Fiscal Year].&[" + @FYear + "].PrevMember")}  I get nothing the cells are blank.

Comment: No, I mean is @FYear actually returning 1314? Is the formatting and everything ok? Test it. That would help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Ok. is the proces like SQL use print @FYear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82155/discussion-between-sourav-agasti-and-john).

Comment: Got it the answer was ,{ StrToSet(@FYear + ".PrevMember")} thank you for your help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti (upped) nice full answer sourav